# Angular HTML element alignment issue

Tags: html, angular, css

[image]

[image]
[image]

I am trying to align the bottom picture to the right of the table. I know that i am missing a small setting here, but cant seem to find it. At the bottom code it is the saleForMonth element that I want to align it to the right.

```
   <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav-content style="height:99vh;">
        <div style="float:left; margin:22px 0px 0px 32px;">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
            </div>
            <button mat-raised-button type="button" style="background-color:#3378a8;color:WHITE;height:45px;" (click)="sidenavOpen('sale',sidenav)">
                <b>SALE</b>
            </button>
            <button mat-raised-button type="button" style="background-color:#3378a8;color:WHITE;height:45px;margin-left:2px;" (click)="sidenavOpen('upgrade',sidenav)">
                <b>UPGRADE</b>
            </button>
            <div style="margin-top:53px">
                <div>
                    <salesByPackage></salesByPackage>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:240px;">
                    <salesByCampaign></salesByCampaign>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;float:right">
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <mat-tab-group #tab mat-stretch-tabs (selectedTabChange)="onTabClick($event)">
                      <mat-tab label="SALES">
                          <orders></orders>
                      </mat-tab>
                      <mat-tab label="UPGRADES">
                          <upgrades></upgrades>
                      </mat-tab>
                  </mat-tab-group>
              </div>
              <!-- Change to this -->
              <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <div>
                      <salesForMonth></salesForMonth>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
```

Comment: have you tried `style="float:right"`? on div

Comment: Yes I already did, it didn't work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row" style="float:right">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <salesForMonth></salesForMonth>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use empty div at the left side and set it with col-lg-9

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-9">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    abc
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for joining in.

Answer (score 0):

If your component `salesForMonth` is not of full width, Try this CSS -

```
    <div style='width:100%; float:right'>
        <salesForMonth></salesForMonth>
    </div>
```

else just put `float:right` on your element.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: its going to be a bit hard with this complex setup I have.

Comment: With putting float:right this way <div style="float:right">
                <salesForMonth></salesForMonth>
            </div> I was able to bring it to the right side bottom to the table.

Comment: OH, so you mean you want it to adjust it right side of table not on bottom right, I am right?

Comment: Yes that is the way I am aiming for

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="container col-lg-9" style="margin-top:20px;float:right">
        <mat-tab-group #tab mat-stretch-tabs (selectedTabChange)="onTabClick($event)">
            <mat-tab label="SALES">
                <orders></orders>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="UPGRADES">
                <upgrades></upgrades>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </div>
    <!-- Change to this -->
    <div class="container col-lg-3">
        <div>
            <salesForMonth></salesForMonth>
        </div>
    </div>
```

put those 2 blocks into `container` and partition them as `col-lg-9` and `col-lg-3`

Comment: I got the 3rd pic uploaded with the above setting. It changed the whole setup

Comment: @Sumchans you sure? coz we made changes to last 2 blocks only.. but your image show changes on 'SHOW' and 'UPGRADE' tab too.. can you show the changes you made?